# Python Urllib/Requests XML iterparse error

Tags: python, xml, parsing, python-requests, urllib

I am currently trying to fetch a XML from Wikipedia and parse it with XML. My general setup is the following:

```
import requests
import xml.etree.cElementTree as etree
payload = {'pages': 'Apple', 'action': 'submit', 'offset' : '2008-01-24 09:39:22'}
r = requests.post('http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special:Export', params=payload, stream=True)
xmlIterator = etree.iterparse(r.raw, events=("start","end"))
```

When I do my parsing syntax, I get the following error:

```
for event, element in self.xmlIterator:
File "&lt;string>", line 107, in next
ParseError: no element found: line 249375, column 2
```

I have tried the same approach with urllib receiving in the same error. It also just seems to happen for this specific XML, others work fine.

But the strange thing is as follows: if I store the response to a file and then pass the file to the XML parser it works fine. E.g.,:

```
open("test.xml","w").write(r.text.encode('utf-8'))
xmlIterator = etree.iterparse("test.xml", events=("start","end"))
```

Again, the same behavior for urllib.

Does anyone have an idea of what the problem could be?

Comment: What version of Python are you using? I just tried your code with 3.4.2, using both your original `xml.etree.cElementTree`, and using `lxml.etree`, and both worked fine...

Comment: It's pretty strange. I solved it by using a pseudo file pointer via FileIO. The thing is that my code is doing some calculations each iteration it parses. Hence, it seems to happen that somehow the stream gets messed up or closed or something like that over time.